# Inconsistent Vectorization Numpy and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I want to vectorize some simple math on a pd.DataFrame. In particular, I want to divide each row of my dataframe by the sum of that row. My problem is that whenever I calculate this using vectorized operations on the dataframe (not df.apply or converting to an actual numpy array) the calculations are off and I am given extra columns in the output dataframe. Is Numpy Vectorization different than Pandas? This is surprising to me...

```
# random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 5)))

# sum of each row
rowSum = np.sum(df, axis=1)

# PANDAS vectorization
divided = df / rowSum 


mdarray = df.values # converts to 2d array
rowSumArray = rowSum.values.reshape(-1, 1) # converts to 1d array

# NUMPY vectorization
dividedArray = mdarray / rowSumArray
```

Sample Code:

Comment: Yes, pandas will try to align on indices. I think the default is *columns* if you just want to use the operator, use `df.divide(rowSum, axis='rows')` to get the output you want

Comment: Should be `divided = df.div(rowSum, axis='rows')`...

Comment: See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#flexible-binary-operations